Use Cookie Authentication for Microsoft Authentication in ASP.NET CORE Identity
I want to use Individual Logins and Microsoft Auth on my Blazor WebApp. Now, for debugging purposes, I don't want to sign in every time to the app. So I thought I can solve it with cookies. The cookie works fine if I log in with an individual account. But when I'm using my Microsoft account to log in, there is no cookie stored and I have to log in again, when opening the browser again.
I followed the Docs on the Microsoft page, but I couldn't really find anything for this specific use-case (probably I'm just stupid).
The goal is, when opening the WebApp, I want to log in with my Microsoft account. When I close the browser and open it again, I want to be logged in. As mentioned before, this works for individual accounts currently but not for Microsoft accounts.
Here is the code:
using BlazorApp1.Components;
using BlazorApp1.Components.Account;
using BlazorApp1.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    }).AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
    {
        microsoftOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
        microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();


var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender<ApplicationUser>, IdentityNoOpEmailSender>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

// Add additional endpoints required by the Identity /Account Razor components.
app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();

app.Run();


It's basically the default template from the Blazor Example with ASP.NET Identity (if you want to try it by yourself).
Thanks in advance for visisting/helping!

Have you tried adding builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie within your program.cs, it seems your shared code doesn't have anything like.

Yes, but I'm not sure of the exact config I need to do it. I tried with the documentation from the Microsoft site, but didn't work like I wanted it.

When saying didn't work, what happend actually? Getting any error or exception or what have you seen in log?
